# Problems with replacing a static id with variable

Tags: javascript, xml, variables, onclick

I have a script that loads info from external XML file and inserts it into the HTML page on click. Here's the code of this script:

```js
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,target) {
xmlhttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for all new browsers
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // code for IE5 and IE6
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (xmlhttp != null) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
}
}
function state_Change() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // 4 = "loaded"
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { // 200 = OK    
        var markers = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            //etc...
document.getElementById(target).innerHTML += '<li>' + name + '</li>\n';
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
    }
}
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
  <ul id="list_puncts">
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadXMLDoc('./content/geo_points/slovenia.xml','list_sl')">Republika Slovenija (RS)</a>
 <ul id="list_sl">
   <!--here should be some info from XML file-->
     </ul></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadXMLDoc('./content/geo_points/horvatia.xml','list_hr')">Republika Hrvatska (RH)</a>
    <ul id="list_hr">
    <!--here should be some info from XML file-->
    </ul></li>
   </ul>
```

However, it does not work - after the link is clicked, XML gets loaded (it can be seen in Firebug), but the second variable - `target` - cannot make its way into the `state_Change` function, so no real action is done. If `target` in 
    `document.getElementById(target).innerHTML`
is replaced by some static id (like `list_sl`), it is working, but I have many of these links in the HTML, not only Slovenia and Horvatia, so the variable is strongly needed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `state_Change` logic in an anonymous function within `loadXMLDoc`.

```
function loadXMLDoc(url,target) {
    // ... code to instantiate XMLHttprequest goes here ...

    if (xmlhttp != null) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Your state_Change() logic goes here.
            // This has access to the variable "target" because
            // it's within the same enclosing function's scope.
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
```

The drawback to this is that a new instance of the function is instantiated each time `loadXMLDoc` is called.

Comment: I deleted, and then undeleted this because I made a mistake in the first version. Sorry, I'm still kind of new on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is kind of very simple solution, also worked for me, thanks Nate

Answer (score 1):

If you use global variables (both for `XMLHttpRequest`s and your `target`s), you can't support parallel requests (i.e. a user clicks on another link before one `XMLHttpRequest` returns). One way to implement it is to keep the `xmlhttp` variable in your `loadXMLDoc` function's scope and add your `target` as a property to the `XMLHttpRequest` object:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url, target) {
    var xmlhttp;
    // create XMLHttpRequest instance
    if(xmlhttp != null) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;
        xmlhttp.targetListId = target;
        xmlhttp.open(); // etc.
    }
};
```

In your `state_Change` function you can access the `XMLHttpRequest` instance using the event's `target` property:

```
function state_Change(e) {
    var xmlhttp = e.target;
    // check readystate & status

    var targetList = document.getElementById(xmlhttp.targetListId);
    targetList.innerHTML = ''; // fill with data, etc.
};
```

Comment: Thank you, i was already desperate to use setTimeout to make the second function wait for the first. This works flawlessly.

Comment: Well, it seems it doesn't work in IE (6-7-8, all of them). Gives 'Message: 'target' is null or not an object' error.

Comment: Sorry, didn't test IE and don't have one on my system. IE has many proprietary features/bugs which is why I strongly encourage you to use a Javascript library to abstract away browser differences.

Comment: Well, I use JQuery most of the time, but in this project don't want to overload the size of the resources.